# SQL Server cakephp 3 in linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, cakephp

How can I connect a SQL Server CAKEPHP 3 database from Linux. I currently have the freetds / pdo_dblib drivers but I still have problems with the driver.

Database driver Cake \ Database \ Driver \ Sqlserver can not be used due to missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

Comment: Does the text in the second paragraph of your post represent an error text you are facing currently?

Comment: You need to install php extension of database you want to use.
http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?